# I want a command block to say something

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am building a village in minecraft and in this village is a little restaurant called Ichiraku's Ramen what i want is when someone walks in it says Hi welcome to ichiraku's ramen, and another command block to say what would you like. but only with a 5 block radius. Please Answer.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Like Frank said, we are not a forum. If you need help fixing a broken command we might be able to help, but we will not create things on demand.

Comment: You may want to read through this. https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/what-to-do-before-asking-a-minecraft-commands-question

Comment: @Dragonrage Do you realize that this question was asked two years before the meta post you linked to?

Comment: @Frank sorry if this question bothered you, but I was literally 12 when I asked it.  I didn't know how to just look it up, or anything about rules, or how to provide more information.  I just wanted to know as it states how to get a command block to say something in chat.  It seems that was too hard to answer for you but luckily someone responded even if I didn't see it, thousands of others did.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command called `/say`. It works like `/say @a[r=5] Hi welcome to ichiraku's ramen.`

Place a command block that is under a block with a pressure plate on top outside of the door, so whenever someone walks past the door it will say "Hi welcome to ichiraku's ramen".